# error: not enough memory for bomb detection (possible zip bomb)

Tags: zip, unzip

I downloaded [MOT17](https://motchallenge.net/data/MOT17/) dataset and when I try to unzip it using: $ unzip MOT17.zip
I get this:
error: not enough memory for bomb detection
error: invalid zip file with overlapped components (possible zip bomb)

so, what's the problem in that?

Answer (score 2):

The ZIP file is just corrupted or unreadable. I advise you to use 7zip on windows or keka on linus for compression. I hope i help you.

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP file was reuploaded (2020-12-18 18:04 CET) and should work now with every zip tool.